# Is Qt invalidating digital signatures of its own libraries at build-time?

Tags: qt, build, digital-signature, qmake, signtool

We've got a couple build systems in place that use Qt. Since we wanted to save time on signing tasks and we're required to sign all unsigned binaries that we distribute, we went ahead and signed all the Qt binaries in their installation location, and for some of our package managers using Qt dependencies, the same type of setup, except that it's packages being signed instead of the local Qt directory on the build slaves.

Today I noticed both on Jenkins and TFS build flows where using Qt projects, this little two-liner shows up in the logs:

> 15:24:19 Updating Qt5Core.dll. 
>   15:24:19 Patching Qt5Core.dll...

Then later on in the build logs for Jenkins, its digital signature was unsuccessfully verified and then signed with a test-cert:

> 15:24:19 `call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64\signtool.exe" verify /pa C:\BuildFolder\artifacts\qt5611_win32-msvc2015\release\Qt5Core.dll`   
>   15:24:19  `IF NOT "!errorlevel!" == "0" echo Self-Signing C:\BuildFolder\artifacts\qt5611_win32-msvc2015\release\Qt5Core.dll  & call signtool sign /f C:\DevOps\test_certificates\cert.pfx /fd SHA512 C:\BuildFolder\artifacts\qt5611_win32-msvc2015\release\Qt5Core.dll  && set something_signed=true` 
>   15:24:19 `)` 
>   15:24:19 File: C:\BuildFolder\artifacts\qt5611_win32-msvc2015\release\Qt5Core.dll  
>   15:24:19 Index  Algorithm  Timestamp 
>   15:24:19 ======================================== 
>   15:24:19 
>   15:24:19 Number of errors: 1 
>    
>   15:24:19 SignTool Error: No signature found. 
>   15:24:19 Self-Signing C:\BuildFolder\artifacts\qt5611_win32-msvc2015\release\Qt5Core.dll 
>   15:24:19 Done Adding Additional Store 15:24:19 Successfully signed: C:\BuildFolder\artifacts\qt5611_win32-msvc2015\release\Qt5Core.dll

Is something from `QMake` or `JOM` invalidating the digital signature from this `Updating`/`Patching` that's happening? If so, is this unavoidable? I'm not well-versed on building Qt projects on other operating systems, but I recall needing to use some tools to change where libs pointed to. The best I can figure is that something like that is happening behind the scenes with `WinDeployQt`.

This is what runs right before the first two quoted lines, if you're interested in what `WinDeployQt` was reporting:

> 15:24:18  `link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /INCREMENTAL:NO /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='removed-by-OP' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" /MANIFEST:embed /OUT:C:\BuildFolder\bin\release\qt_test_build.exe @C:\Users\USER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\qt_test_build.exe.4012.485.jom` 
>   15:24:19  `windeployqt -core --no-compiler-runtime --no-quick-import --no-translations` `C:\BuildFolder\solution_directory\..\bin\release\qt_test_build.exe` 
>   15:24:19 C:\BuildFolder\bin\release\qt_test_build.exe 64 bit, release executable 
>   15:24:19 Direct dependencies: Qt5Core 
>   15:24:19 All dependencies   : Qt5Core 
>   15:24:19 To be deployed : Qt5Core

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`qmake` doesn't modify anything besides its output: its only job is to generate build scripts for another build system.

`jom` is a make tool and does what `nmake` would do, except in multiple processes in parallel if possible. It merely follows directions in the makefiles. I don't know of any code in `qmake` that would generate makefile actions that modify Qt libraries themselves - not unless you put something explicit in the project file that will cause this. I've never seen it happen either.

That leaves `windeployqt`, and it does patch Qt binaries after they are **copied** to the target location, since the binaries contain some embedded paths etc. If you invoke `windeployqt` via your makefile/project file, then it will appear as if Qt has been modified from within `job`.

Observe that the Qt binaries in original locations that you've signed remain so. In fact, your Qt installation after signing should be made read-only and have the permission set such that the build itself cannot mess it up, unless the Qt installation step is a part of the build itself.

Alas, there's a simple fix: sign stuff right before you build your install package - that'll certainly be *after* `windeployqt`. Works for me (tm). A static build could perhaps be an option as well if your product consists of one executable, or could be made to be that way.

Comment: Dag nammit! I had a feeling that was what was going on, or similar >_< I guess it is feasible to make their output locations statically signed and committed for the Qt DLLs. I can probably get away with this for the smaller repos, but I have a feeling Mother Mercy in DevOps will break out the ruler and rice-kneels xD But that's _my_ problem, not yours! Thanks, Kuba Ober!

Answer (score 1):

Things became better in Qt 5.14.2.

In older **Qt 5.13.2** I can find *qt_prfxpath=* in Qt5Core.dll that is followed by my local path to that file. *windeployqt* replaces this path with "." and writes to log about it:

> Patching Qt5Core.dll...

After that "patching" the Authenticode signature of Qt5Core.dll becomes valid 
(it's invalid on my local file d:\Qt\5.13.2\mingw73_64\bin\Qt5Core.dll). It seems like the Qt installer patches Qt5Core.dll and *windeployqt* restores it to it's factory default state. IMHO, it was a terrible design solution.

Now, in **Qt 5.14.2** I don't see "qt_prfxpath=" any more and *windeployqt* doesn't patch it. The signature of my local file d:\Qt\5.14.2\mingw73_64\bin\Qt5Core.dll is already valid.

So, it seems that Qt authors have removed this ugly patching. If so, *windeployqt* is not a required step any more. This utility gets too many excessive libraries, at least for my project. I'm going to get rid of it and copy everything explicitly in my build script.

Comment: That's great to hear! I think it was just a bad artefact for when they ported their process from *nix to Windows. You typically have to patch lib locations when copying and bundling them by changing the path or something along those lines for dedicated standalone modules/apps when assuming they're not installed independently by the user. In Windows-land its simpler and image lookups for paths follow a set scheme making it pretty friendly for just copying them right into the directory without modifying the file. tl;dr it was probably overengineered and problematic before.